# JPA with @Param null parameters still throwing errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've read a number of posts on here relating to JPA handling of null params.

Many solutions have offered the following workaround using native queries, see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-null-parameters

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE (:name is null or c.name = :name) and (:email is null or c.email = :email)")
List<Customer> findCustomerByNameAndEmail(@Param("name") String name, @Param("email") String email);
```

However this still doesn't work in my case I get the following error when running a test

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter of type String at index 0 in customer.name must not be null!
```

Is there something in the entity/repo that needs configured to prevent throwing the illegal args. Desired outcome would be "ignoring" of null value and just return me everything in that case.

I am aware of the following: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-209 still unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding Nullable annotation -

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE (:name is null or c.name = :name) and (:email is null or c.email = :email)")
List<Customer> findCustomerByNameAndEmail(@Nullable @Param("name") String name, @Nullable @Param("email") String email);
```